# Reusing javascript objects after removing the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have this problem. I have a `Javascript` object, created via `var stack = {}`. In the project the object is used to store arrays. When the add button is clicked an array is added to the object with a key. The key is a value input in an HTML input field. The added button can be clicked as many times as the user pleases. Once the submit button is clicked the data is sent via `ajax` to `php`. On a successful return `stack` is cleared and the document is ready to be used to again. The functions below are example code of the implementation.

**Add.js**

```
function add(stack){
      ...
      var arr = ['apple','oranges'];
      stack[someName] = arr; 
}
```

**Submit.js**

```
function submit(stack){
      $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "somefile.php",
            success: function(html){
                //some event
                ...
                //remove elements in stack
                stack = {};
            }
       });
}
```

**Main.js**

```
var stack = {};
$('#addButtonId').on('click',function(){
    add(stack);
}
$('#sumbitButtonId').on('click',function(){
    submit(stack);
}
```

The problem is that once the submit button is press and the object is cleared. The object `stack` wont hold any new array if the addButton is clicked again. Can someone explain to me whats going on? I read somewhere that clearing the object with `obj = {}` leave garbage. But Im not entirely sure what it means or if it entails to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what you've shown your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uayu70dd

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
for (var member in stack) {
  delete stack[member];
}
```

when doing `stack = {}`, you're just setting it to a new empty object, not clearing out its contents. although, for all intents and purposes, that should work just fine so I'm not sure if the error is where you think it is occurring.

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object which contains arrays. He's just using bracket notation.

Comment: i.e, `stack = { 'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6] };`

Comment: ah that guy deleted his comment so it looks like I'm talking to myself. ;)

Comment: I havent gone and tried the `delete` method you suggested yet. But if I console.log the `stack `data after add. I get a new object that holds `{['apple','oranges']}` . Then if I console.log it in the submit function before the ajax call it returns `{}`.